# Using Python Pillow to 'Punch' Out transparency Using Second Image

Tags: python, merge, python-imaging-library, alpha

I am currently trying to use an RGBA image to 'punch' out a hole in another RGBA image but all my current attempts have failed to maintain the original transparency. Once I apply an alpha channel using putalpha it will replace the original alpha channel completely and turn previously transparent pixels back to their original colors.

I am trying to perform a "putalpha" on only the pixels with 100% transparency.

In the photos below I attempt to overlap an 'inverted transparency' alpha channel on top of my Circle to perform the 'punch out'. Instead of only applying the transparent pixels it will replace the entire image's alpha which turns the rest of the circle image's transparency white.

Is there a way for me to do this transparency "Merge" to achieve an alpha layer that is a composite of both images?

```py
#image2 is a square, image1 is a circle

# swapTransparency is a function I made that works in swapping the transparency, it just goes pixel by pixel and switches alpha channel value to # max where empty and to 0 everywhere else. 
# probably a better and more effective way to invert the transparency but this works right now and might not even be needed. 
def swapTransparency(img):

    datas = img.getdata()

    newData = []
    for item in datas:
       if item [3] == 0:
            newData.append((0, 0, 0, 255))
       else:
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))

    img.putdata(newData)
    return img


##This is putting alpha channel overtop but its replacing the entire alpha instead of merging them, losing original cricle transparency. 
image2 = swapTransparency(image2)
alphaChannel = image2.getchannel('A')
image1.putalpha(image2)
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg64q.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9mxY.png)

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urjiI.png)

Comment: There seems to be lots of punching going on, but no input images...

Comment: @MarkSetchell hey not sure what you mean by that, are you not able to see the images?

Comment: Your question implies you have 2-3 input images and some punching is done and there's a result. But I only see 2 results, but no input images... and no code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can update with some code & photos to make it more clear! Yeah it makes sense I didnt include enough, sorry about that!